# How to use threads inside a class that act as a countdown timer?

Tags: python, multithreading, oop, timer

I want to define an object that contains an `id`, `status` and `countdown timer`. As soon as I instantiate this object, the countdown timer should set off immediately.

Below is the code where I create a class that has a non threaded version of the countdown timer defined in it

```
import time
import sys
from threading import Timer

class UserTimer:
    def __init__(self, id=None, current_status=None):
        self.id = id
        self.current_status = current_status
        self.timeout()

    def timeout(self):
        print("timeout started for", self.id)
        timeout_limit = 150
        seconds = 0
        while True:
            try:
                if seconds == timeout_limit:
                    print("countdown over for", self.id)
                    break
                time.sleep(1)
                seconds += 1
            except KeyboardInterrupt, e:
                break
```

Below is how an instantiate it

```
params1 = {'id': "test@hello.com", 'current_status': "success"}
params2 = {'id': "test2@hello.com", 'current_status': "success"}
user1 = UserTimer(**params1)
user2 = UserTimer(**params2)
```

The problem here is that when this program runs, it will instantiate the first object (`user1`) and due to the function `time.sleep()`, it will wait for the given duration before instantiating the second object (`user2`)

So I then looked up and found python threads helpful in this situation since the threads will run independent and won't block the progression of the code.

So this is how I changed the code below

```
class UserTimer:
    def __init__(self, id=None, current_status=None):
        self.id = id
        self.current_status = current_status

    def timeout(self):
        print("time over for", self.id)


    t = Timer(150, timeout)
    t.start()


params1 = {'id': "test@hello.com", 'current_status': "success"}
params2 = {'id': "test2@hello.com", 'current_status': "success"}
user1 = UserTimer(**params1)
user2 = UserTimer(**params2)
```

Now both the objects get instantiated simultaneously but the problem is as soon as the given duration is over, it gives the following error

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 1073, in run
    self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
TypeError: timeout() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

This is because it sees the keyword `self` which it doesn't expect. But I need the `self` since I need to dump some information about the user object. If I remove `self`, then it runs fine.

Am I defining threads inside a class in a wrong manner? What I want is to be able to instantiate multiple objects that have their own countdown timers.

Additionally I should also be able to reset the countdown timer by doing something like `user1.reset_timer = True`

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put Timer initialization in `__init__()` to start it when you instantiate an object.

```py
class UserTimer(object):
    def __init__(self, id=None, current_status=None):
        self.id = id
        self.current_status = current_status
        self.start_timer()   # start timer when an object is instantiated

    def timeout(self):
        print("time over for", self.id)

    def start_timer(self):
        self.t = Timer(5, self.timeout)  # changed to 5 seconds for demo                                                 
                                         # `self.timeout` instead of `timeout`
        self.t.start()

    def reset_timer(self):
        self.t.cancel()      # cancel old timer
        self.start_timer()   # and start a new one

params1 = {'id': "test@hello.com", 'current_status': "success"}
params2 = {'id': "test2@hello.com", 'current_status': "success"}
user1 = UserTimer(**params1)

time.sleep(2)     # assuming that user2 is instantiated 2 seconds later
print('instantiating user2...')
user2 = UserTimer(**params2)

time.sleep(3)     # reset user1's timer 3 seconds after user2 instantiation
print('reseting timer of user1...')
user1.reset_timer()
```

You can run the code and check the timing.

Comment: great! This is what I was not able to figure out. Thanks for helping me out!

Answer (score 2):

I was getting a different error from your code than you were:

```
TypeError: timeout() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

The clue is the mention of `self` which was being caused by the:

```
    t = Timer(150, timeout)
    t.start()
```

you had in the class body of `UserTimer`, which means it gets executed when the class is defined (and no `self` instance has been created yet).

A simple way to fix that is to make instances of the class callable by defining a `__call__()` method (and calling it at the right time). Here's what I mean:

```
import time
import sys
from threading import Timer


class UserTimer:
    def __init__(self, id=None, current_status=None, interval=5):
        self.id = id
        self.current_status = current_status
        self.interval = interval

    def timeout(self):
        print("time over for", self.id)

    def __call__(self):
        self.timer_thread = Timer(self.interval, self.timeout)
        self.timer_thread.start()

    def cancel(self):
        try:
            self.timer_thread.cancel()
        except AttributeError:
            raise RuntimeError("'UserTimer' object not started.")


params1 = dict(id="test@hello.com", current_status="success")
params2 = dict(id="test2@hello.com", current_status="success", interval=6)
user1 = UserTimer(**params1)
user1()  # Start Timer.
user2 = UserTimer(**params2)
user2()  # Start Timer.
```

I also added the `cancel()` method as you requested and made the time interval an easily changed variable instead of hardcoding it into the body of the class as well.

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation. Didn't know about the `__call__` attribute and how it can be used in situation like this. If I understood it right, one advantage I see with this approach is that I can instantiate the object but choose to run the timer later at any point. This can be handy in certain situations.

Comment: Adding a `__call__()` method is just one way of implementing things. It's convenient if instances of your class only do one thing (like start running) and using it would have allowed you to simply write `UserTimer(**params1)()`. However since you want to also be able to cancel one after starting it, you're going to need to store the instance in a variable in order to call that method — it's not as applicable in this case IMO. A third alternative not mentioned so far would be to call the `Timer.start()` method in your class' `__init__()` so that just creating one would automatically start it.